# How to generate random ID and test scores for a a struct of 10 students

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, random, struct

this is my first programming assignment for C, and I am very confused on how to implement random numbers. In my program I have already created a struct student, and created an array with 10 of those students. Now I have to generate random ID numbers and test scores for those 10 students, but my teacher was never clear how to exactly do that. I am also not allowed to change the variables or function declarations. Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct student {
     int id;
     int score;
};

struct student *allocate() {
     return calloc(sizeof(struct student), 10);
}

void generate(struct student* students){
     /*
      *Generate random ID and scores for 10 students, ID being between 0 and 
      * scores equal to (id* 10 % 50)
      */
}
int main() {
     struct student *stud = allocate();
     generate(stud);

    return 0;
}
```

He also gives this instruction:
"Write a function `void generate(struct student* students)` that populates the id and score fields of the array of 10 students passed as an argument. Each student should have an id that corresponds to their index in the array (i.e. the first student in the array should have id 0). If each student's id is x, the student's score should be `(10 * x) % 50`."

Comment: Where in the instruction does it say "random"? "an id that corresponds to their index in the array" is not random and neither is "score should be (10 * x) % 50".

Comment: The instruction does not say "random numbers". It specifically says the numbers are to be based on the index in the array.

Comment: See that's where I was confused too, as in the comments of the skeleton he gave the students it says random but the actual instructions do not

Comment: @McGradyMan So it's a problem with the requirements. Stackoverflow can't help you clear that up. Only your teaching staff can do that. Go ask them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. `struct student*` is used for iterating through the 10 students, where `students` points to the first of the 10 consecutively stored students. Note that `s++` increases the pointer by the size of `struct student`:

```
void generate(struct student* students){
    /*
     *Generate random ID and scores for 10 students, ID being between 0 and
     * scores equal to (id* 10 % 50)
     */
    struct student* s = &students[0];
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        s->id = i;
        s->score = (i*10)%50;
        s++;
    }
}
```

Note that - as pointed out by DYZ - you could also iterate through by directly using variable `students`; It's a matter of liking whether one wants to preserve the originally passed value or not:

```
void generate(struct student* students){
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        students->id = i;
        students->score = (i*10)%50;
        students++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need `struct student* s = &students[0];`, again? Just remove this line, and everything will work.

Comment: @DYZ: you are right; its just my favour not to operate on parameters directly;

Comment: Its not the parameter that you change, but a copy of it, anyway.

Comment: But if you erase that line it doesn't initialize the s variable. How should I initialize that?